# Get an error if I run the pml drush command line

Tags: drush

I just started to use Drush and I think I have some miss-configuration somewhere. 
I use MAMP (on mac) and s/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/subastas is the folder for the Drupal installation.

The error tells me the site has not a configured database, but that is not true since the site is running just fine.

When I try to run the **pml** command I get this error message:

> Dooghouse-iMac:subastas doghouse$ drush pml
>
> `PDO::__construct()`: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to      [warning]
>     connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) environment.inc:517
>     Command pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need [error]
>     invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this
>     command.
>     The drush command 'lml' could not be executed.                       [error]
>     Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
>     Hint: This error often occurs when Drush is trying to bootstrap a
>     site that has not been installed or does not have a configured
>     database.
>
> Drush was attempting to connect to:
>       Drupal version    : 7.9
>       Site URI          : `http://default`
>       Database driver   : mysql
>       Database hostname : localhost
>       Database username : drupal
>       Database name     : subastas
>       Default theme     : garland
>       Administration theme: garland
>       PHP configuration :
>       Drush version     : 5.2
>       Drush configuration:
>       Drupal root       : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/subastas
>       Site path         : sites/default
>       Modules path      : sites/all/modules
>       Themes path       : sites/all/themes
>       File directory path: sites/default/files
>       %paths            : Array
>
> You can select another site with a working database setup by
>     specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command
>     line or `$options['uri']` in your drushrc.php file.

This is the error message shown when using `drush si`:

> My-Name-iMac:drupal-7.14 myname$ drush si --db-url=mysql://root:drupal@localhost:8889/d14
>       You are about to CREATE  the 'd14' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
>       sh: mysql: command not found
>       Starting Drupal installation. This takes a few seconds …           [ok]
>       WD php: Warning: `PDO::__construct()`: [2002] No such file or directory [warning]
>       (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in
>       `DatabaseConnection->__construct()` (line 304 of
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.14/includes/database/database.inc).
>       WD php: Exception: In order for Drupal to work, and to continue with [error]
>       the installation process, you must resolve all issues reported below.
>       For more help with configuring your database server, see the
>       installation handbook. If you are unsure what any of this means you
>       should probably contact your hosting provider.Failed to connect to
>       your database server. The server reports the following message:
>       SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. Is the database
>       server running? Does the database exist, and have you entered the
>       correct database name?Have you entered the correct username and
>       password? Have you entered the correct database hostname? in
>       install_run_task() (line 417 of
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.14/includes/install.core.inc).
>       WD php: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already  [warning]
>       sent by (output started at
>       /Users/myname/Documents/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:37) in
>       drupal_send_headers() (line 1239 of
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.14/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>       Exception:
>
> In order for Drupal to work, and to continue with the installation process, you must resolve all issues reported below. For more help with configuring your database server, see the [installation handbook](http://drupal.org/getting-started/install). If you are unsure what any of this means you should probably contact your hosting provider.
>
> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: *SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory*.
>
> - Is the database server running?
> - Does the database exist, and have you entered the correct database name?
> - Have you entered the correct username and password?
> - Have you entered the correct database hostname?
>
> in install_run_task() (line 417 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.14/includes/install.core.inc).
>       Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]

Comment: Have you tried other commands that also require a database connection? This can help to determine if it's a command-specific issue, or a site-specific one. Also you might try using command line options like drush -r /foo -l http://foo.example.com to test whether it's being called correctly.

Comment: Just as a side-note, your site reports it's using Drupal 7.9 which has security vulnerabilities...might be a good idea to upgrade to the latest version. I doubt that the Drupal version is causing you error though

Comment: You are right, any command related to database connection give the same error. What can I do? The database is fine since the website is running without problem. I found this post that maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819592/error-when-connecting-to-mysql-using-php-pdo

Comment: in php.ini I have **mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock** I think is correct.

Comment: Is it the free version of MAMP ? I think I remember struggling with it when trying to do things outside of its intended scope. Also check that you're reading the correct php.ini : the one for CLI (which drush uses), not the one for the http server.

Comment: It's the free version. The php.ini is located at: **/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've got \`PDOException: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory\` when using drush](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99446/ive-got-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-when-u)

Answer (score 14):

I fixed by running these lines in the terminal.

```bsh
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Post about this here: http://www.mostafaberg.com/2011/08/fixing-the-unixvarmysqlmysql-sock-not-found-error-on-mamp/

Comment: This fixed my problem. I was experiencing the exact same error and after executing the a suggested commands the error went away. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Find path to your `mysql.sock` (e.g. run: `mysql_config --socket`), then add extra line (with `unix_socket`) to your `settings.php` file:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'unix_socket' => '/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
    // ... (other options)
```

Where `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` is your full path to your `mysql.sock` file.